# Determining VA rating of the small transformers

Tags: transformer, power-engineering

I have a 1000VA toroid transformer which weighs 8 Kg. Based on this power-to-weight ratio, can I conclude that another transformer which is EI cored and weighs 7 Kg must be 875VA? Or such ratiometrics only applicable to the transformer of similar core types?

For information, the EI cored transformer is labelled only with its primary and secondary voltages, no current ratings are stated. Its primary voltage is similar as the toroid, 245V 50 Hertz but secondaries are not same voltage.

Toroid's secondary is 35V @ 29 amps
EI core's secondary is 110V, max current not stated.

Comment: Only within similar core types- also there is some variability with quality of core, insulation type and so on.

Comment: So how do I determine its VA?

Comment: Does it state 50 Hz or is that an assumption?

Comment: If you can't find the manufacturer's  data you can't really, you can just make guesses. As a wag once said- test it under worst case conditions until it burns out then back it off a bit. You can test under load for the winding temperature with an ohmmeter (let it heat up for a few hours) but if you don't know whether it's class H insulation or whatever you have no idea whether it's safe or not at that temperature.

Comment: The operating frequency is not an assumption. The details of primary is well defined because I salvage it from K&S gold wire bonder which operates on 245 volt 50 Hz. The machine power is not the metric for the transformer power because the machine is also using a quite large switching power supply for other low voltages.

Comment: Generally toroidal transformers are smaller and lighter than similarly rated EI core transformers, so your EI core transformer probably has a lower rating than a simple ratio would suggest . And as mentioned, it can also vary by wiring, insulation, and other factors.

Comment: To determine the VA rating, assume it's flux density limited and not thermally limited (most transformers are), then measure the cross section area of the core. You should be able to do this without unwinding anything. Then it's just Vt=NAB where V is voltage, t is time, N is number of turns, a is cross section area and B is peak flux density. All in SI units. Since you are running sine wave, you can simplify it to Urms=4.44fNAB, where f is line frequency. Aim for B=0.8 and find N. Use a wire resonable thick so that N turns fills half of your winding area. Assume 4 A/mm^2. Voila! VA rating!